# Localization for COM+ assemblies

Tags: vb.net, localization, com+

I have two projects in my solution:

- ClassLibrary1 (Class Library), which contains

  - a class `Class1`, with a public method: Public Shared Function
    GetMyValue() As String Return My.Resources.MyResource.MyVariable End
    Function
  - Two resource files - MyResource.resx and MyResource.de.resx, both of them contain a string resource named myVariable with the value
    'default' (in MyResource.resx) and 'de' (in MyResource.de.resx).
- TempLocalization project (Windows Forms), with only one form and the OnLoad event handler.

The code:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("de")
MessageBox.Show(Class1.GetMyValue())
```

When I run the project, the correct value is shown, which is "de". But when I set the ClassLibrary1 project's 'Make assembly COM-visible' option and install it into COM+ environment, then this doesn't work anymore - the MessageBox displays the value "default".

How can I correctly localize my COM+ assembly?

Comment: Yes, this is troublesome.  This is actually implemented by the CLR host, ICLRTaskManager::SetUILocale() method.  This cannot flow from one process to another.  Using CurrentCulture instead might work, not so sure.